# Node.js application -- how to build and package for production deployment?

Tags: node.js, packaging, production-environment

I have a node.js application with package.json which in turn have devDependencies and dependencies. The node application also has tests.

In the build machine, I run 'npm install' so that dev-dependencies are installed, then tests are run (tests need dev-dependencies). Then a zip is created with all node_modules and other needed files. Note that the node_modules dir contains all dev-dependencies as well.

My desire is to zip and package only the production-dependencies (and exclude the dev-dependencies). So, what should I do?

If I set NODE_ENV=production then my dev-dependencies do not get installed and this halts the build. If I package the entire node_modules dir, then I am packaging the dev-dependencies also.

What is the best approach for building and packaging for production? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just run `npm install --production` on deployment so that the required production dependencies are installed on the spot?

Comment: Well, the production environment does not have internet access.

Comment: If your prod environment does not have internet access, question is how do u upload to that environment?